# Use Ruby ActiveRecord Validates_Numericality to accept 20.00 as integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

We are working with web development firm to build a site. We have a field where we request that the user input the amount that they would like to invest. We asked for this field to be limited to whole numbers. For example, the user should be able to invest "20" or "20.00" but not "20.50".

The developer is using Ruby ActiveRecord Validate_numericality :only_integer which is restricting the input to "20". If a user inputs and submits the value "20.00" they receive an error telling them that they need to input an integer.

Is there a way to use ActiveRecrod validate_numericality to accept only numbers that are whole numbers, not necessarily only integers? The code is currently:

`validates :principal, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to:MINIMUM_INVESTMENT_AMOUNT,
less_than_or_equal_to:MAXIMUM_INVESTMENT_AMOUNT, 
:only_integer => true}`

I am hoping that there is a numericality constraint that will allow 20.00 as a whole number.

Comment: Do you want to allow the user to input floats and convert them to integers `before_validation` or do you want to raise a validation error if they try to submit the form with decimals?

Comment: I would like to allow the user to input floats (i.e. 20.00) but only raise validation errors if the float != a whole number (i.e. 20.50). I'm not sure if that answers your question.

Comment: It does. @engineersmnky's answer should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do this

```
before_validation {|a| a.principal = principal.to_i}
```

This will convert it to an integer without modifying the validations but if you want to notify the user that they entered something that is not a whole number then I would remove the `:only_integer` and create a more flexible validation like

```
validates :principal, numericality:{greater_than_or_equal_to:MINIMUM_INVESTMENT_AMOUNT, less_than_or_equal_to:MAXIMUM_INVESTMENT_AMOUNT}
validate :principal_is_whole_number

def principal_is_whole_number
  errors.add(:principal, "must be a whole number.") unless principal.to_i == principal
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Just to make sure I am understanding, the ".to_i" function will take 20.00 and return 20, so checking to make sure principal.to_i == principal is making sure that 20 == 20.00. This means that a value of 20.50 would make it such that 20 != 20.50 and return the error. Is this correct?

Comment: @krewllobster correct `20 == 20.00 #=> true` but `20 == 20.5 #=> false`. Also just a note floats do not have trailing zeros beyond the tenths place(just because this indicates them as a `Float`). `20.00000` will return as `20.0`  but `20.0001` will still be `20.0001`

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll pass this on to our devs.